# Unable to reload content tree from other tree in Umbraco using angular

Tags: angularjs, umbraco, umbraco7

We have some Javascript inside our angular control in the developer tree which needs to refresh the content tree.

We can't call `navigationService.syncTree({ tree: 'content'...` because it returns an error - `Could not find the tree content, activeTree has not been set`.

We can get it to work by calling `changeSection('content')` - THEN WAITING (timeout) - then calling `navigationService.syncTree(`.

Obviously that sucks. It seems that `changeSection` isn't blocking and doesn't return a promise. I assume therefore what we need to do is listen to an event from the treeService once it's actually switched - but the treeService doesn't seem to be available! :(

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't navigate a tree which is not active. So why would you want to sync an inactive tree? And second question, have you posted this on the umbraco forums http://our.umbraco.org?

Comment: @dampee Because the content has changed. Yes I've posted there too. Noone replied to my last two posts on our.umbraco.